# How to list the own vector elements?

Tags: java, vector, imagej

i have got an own vector.class and a polygon.class
Vector.class

```
package org.onvif.ver10.schema;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlType(name = "Vector")

public class Vector {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "x")
    protected Float x;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "y")
    protected Float y;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the x property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Float }
     *     
     */
    public Float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the x property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Float }
     *     
     */
    public void setX(Float value) {
        this.x = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the y property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Float }
     *     
     */
    public Float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the y property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Float }
     *     
     */
    public void setY(Float value) {
        this.y = value;
    }
    }
```

and the polygon class

```
public class Polygon {

@XmlElement(name = "Point", required = true)
protected List<Vector> point;

/**
 * Gets the value of the point property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the point property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getPoint().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link Vector }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<Vector> getPoint() {
    if (point == null) {
        point = new ArrayList<Vector>();
    }
    return this.point;
}

}
```

So, i give the vector elements:

```
org.onvif.ver10.schema.Vector MyVector = new Vector(); // létrehozzuk az
                                                                // onvif féle
                                                                // vector-t
        org.onvif.ver10.schema.Polygon op = new org.onvif.ver10.schema.Polygon();

        for (int i = 1; i <= p.npoints; i++) {
//          IJ.log("X: "+ i);
//          MyVector.setX((float) p.xpoints[i]); // hozzáadjuk az elemet
//          MyVector.setY((float) p.ypoints[i]);

            MyVector.setX((float)p.xpoints[i-1]);
            op.getPoint().add(MyVector);
            IJ.log("Vector X Elements "+i+" :"+ MyVector.getX());

        }
        IJ.log("Op size " + op.getPoint().size());
```

My question is how can i get the op (onvif polygon) elements?
Because i no matter how i try i just got the last element 10 times.

Comment: you could use `javax.vecmath.Vector2f` class instead creating a Vector class with 2 floats...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is that you are adding the same `Vector` instance to the polygon 10 times and setting the points on that one instance over and over.

Your code should be changed to move the `new Vector()` line *inside* the loop:

```
    org.onvif.ver10.schema.Polygon op = new org.onvif.ver10.schema.Polygon();

    for (int i = 1; i <= p.npoints; i++) {
        org.onvif.ver10.schema.Vector MyVector = new Vector(); 
        MyVector.setX((float)p.xpoints[i-1]);
        op.getPoint().add(MyVector);
        IJ.log("Vector X Elements "+i+" :"+ MyVector.getX());

    }
```

Style issues with your code include, but are not limited to:

- Variable names should start with a lowercase letter, so `myVector` not `MyVector`
- Never create class names synonymous with JDK classes (like `Vector`)

Comment: Thx , i'll try your answer. I didn't named it vector.class it's an onvif.xsd that made these calsses.
How can i print the op elements outsiede the loop?

Comment: @user1620554 you can use `for(Vector v : op.getPoint()){IJ.log("Vector X Elements :"+ v.getX());}`

Comment: thx it's working :)
one more question: i managed it the first for loop starts with 1, and the p.xpoints ends with i-1... can u tell me why?